# exponential potential quantization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

What are the energies $E_{n}$ of the Schroedinger operator

$$ -\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}y(x)+ae^{bx}y(x)=E_{n}y(x) $$

for some real and positive 'a' and 'b' with the Boundary conditions $ y(0)=0=y(\infty) $?

Working a bit I get the quantization condition

$$ J_{E_{n}/4}(\sqrt{-a})=0,$$

($ J_{a}(x) $ is a Bessel function) but unfortunately this equation yields only imaginary roots.

Comment: Did you mean $e^{bx}$ ?

Comment: re yes ,. Michael has corrected the equation.

Comment: Please check my edits are what you meant, particularly re: the order of the Bessel function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [exponential potential $ \exp(|x|) $](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47128/)