# quantization with a pure exponential potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantization

Given the Hamiltonian 
$$ H=p^{2}-ge^{-x}, $$
are the energies negative?

If I impose the boundary condition $y(0)=0$ and $y(\infty)=0$, I get the condition for the energies
$$ J_{2i \sqrt{E(n)}}(g) =0 $$
where $J_{a}(x)$ is a [Bessel function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel_functions_of_the_first_kind_%3a_J.CE.B1).

Unfortunately, this is too hard to solve, so how can I obtain the quantization of the energy levels in the WKB approximation?

Comment: I'm not sure the WKB approximation is good here, because the potential is not slowly varying (for small x, at least)

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47128/2451 and links therein.

Comment: What does $y$ represent?

Comment: @JeffDror: OP's related question (linked by Qmechanic) shows $y$ as the wavefunction (instead of the more common $\psi$).